# spring jpa nested projection generating incorrect query

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, projection

Lets consider these entities

```java
@Entity
public class Room{

  @Id
  private Integer id;

  private String number;

  private String floor;

  @ManyToOne
  private RoomType roomType;

  // Setters & Getters  
}

@Entity
public class RoomType{

  @Id
  private Integer id;

  private String name;

  private String description;

  private Boolean enabled;

  // Setters & Getters  
}
```

And also this interface for projection alongside repository class

```java
public interface RoomList{

    public Number getId();

    public String getNumber();

    public RoomType getRoomType();

    interface RoomType {
        String getName();
    }   

}

@Repository
public interface RoomRepository extends JpaRepository<Room,Integer>{

    public Collection<RoomList> findAllProjectedBy();

}
```

Now if I look at generated SQL

```
select
    room0_.id as col_0_0_,
    room0_.number as col_1_0_,
    roomtype1_.id as id1_3_,
    roomtype1_.description as descript2_3_,
    roomtype1_.enabled as isActive3_3_,
    roomtype1_.name as name5_3_ 
from
    Room room0_ 
inner join
    roomType roomtype1_ 
        on room0_.roomType_id=roomtype1_.id
```

**The generated query should be something like this**

```
select
    room0_.id as col_0_0_,
    room0_.number as col_1_0_,
    roomtype1_.name as name5_3_ 
from
    Room room0_ 
inner join
    roomType roomtype1_ 
        on room0_.roomType_id=roomtype1_.id
```

Can someone explain this behaviour or either this is a bug ? also what other options do we have achieve this kind of result. I already tried JPA entitygraph but graph type fetch is not yet fully supported in hibernate, i don't want to use constructor jpql query either. Thanks !

Comment: Can you share the definition of `findAllProjectedBy` ?
When you haven't described when the Query is generated what operation you performed.

Comment: `findAllProjectedBy()` works exactly like `findAll()` except I can only return `List<Room>` in `findAll()` but i can return `List<RoomList>` in `findAllProjectedBy()` or whatever i want.

Comment: You have `RoomType` as an `interface` and as well as `class`, have you considered changing it.

Comment: I have `RoomType` as an class but not as an interface. Interface name is `RoomList` and configuration is as per spring data jpa reference documentation [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections).

[edit] `RoomType` inner interface is required for nested projections.

Comment: `RoomType` inner interface is required by spring data jpa for nested projections also all configurations are correct.

Comment: Consider changing their names like `RoomTypeSummary` or something like that.

Comment: Changing interface name to `RoomTypeSummary` gives runtime error as there is no field specified as `RoomTypeSummary` in `Room` entity.

Comment: [Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) gives example of nested class between `Person` and `Address`, have you considered making the `RoomType` nested class of `Room`

Comment: This also have another issue. it always use inner join when query projection no matter what `(@JoinColumn(nullable=true) )` nullable is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If understand correctly the concern is that more attributes/columns get selected than necessary to fill the projections.

As I just described in [issue DATAJPA-1218](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1218) this is just how projections work in Spring Data currently. The attributes of referenced entities do not get limited to those used in the projection.