# Projections do not load ManyToOne relations lazily

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, lazy-loading, projection

I have an entity representing a MySQL table:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "group_")
@Getter
@Setter
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GroupEntity
        implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "group_id")
    private UUID groupId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_account_id")
    @NotNull
    private AccountEntity ownerAccount;

    @Column(name = "value")
    @NotBlank
    private String value;

}
```

And a projection:

```java
public interface GroupBaseProjection {

    UUID getGroupId();

    AccountEntity getOwnerAccount();

}
```

This is my repository:

```java
public interface GroupsRepository extends JpaRepository<GroupEntity, UUID> {

    GroupBaseProjection findBaseByGroupId(UUID groupId);

}
```

When I retrieve the entity, the `ownerAccount` is loaded lazily (the Hibernate MySQL query only selects its ID) but when I retrieve the projection, it is loaded eagerly (the Hibernate MySQL query does an inner join with all the `AccountEntity` columns). So there is no way I can retrieve only some columns of the `GroupEntity` (I have to retrieve all of them using the entity, or some of them plus all the columns of the `AccountEntity` using the projection).

Is there a way I can get the projection to load the `@ManyToOne` relation lazily? I've tried annotating the `getOwnerAccount()` method of projection with `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)` and `@LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.PROXY)` but it did not work.

Comment: You shouldn't use projection that contain Entities. Instead you should just select the columns you need

Comment: I can do that but (1) it won't make a difference since nested projections select all columns, not just the defined ones in the getters, and (2) I don't want to get some columns from the account table, I just want the id (I don't want to see the inner join even if it is with just the id column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So there is no way I can retrieve only some columns of the GroupEntity

<strike>Sure there is, just use a nested projection:</strike>

```
public interface AccountProjection {

    Long getId();

    String getName();

   ... // other columns

} 

public interface GroupBaseProjection {

    UUID getGroupId();

    AccountProjection getOwnerAccount();

}
```

> Is there a way I can get the projection to load the @ManyToOne relation lazily?

I wouldn't think so, since projections are not entities, and so they are not managed by JPA.

EDIT It would seem nested projections select all the entity properties anyway (see comments). As a workaround, if you're only interested in the id, you could try mapping the join column once again as a simple property:

```
@Column(name = "owner_account_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Long ownerAccountId;
```

this way, you'll be able to make it part of the projection.

Comment: Nested projections retrive all columns, even if they have only some of them defined in the getters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47159647/spring-jpa-nested-projection-generating-incorrect-query https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/1555 (I also tried it)

Comment: @s3curitybug Oops, didn't realize that. See my updated answer for a possible workaround

Comment: That's a possibility, but it feels like a dirty hack.